Integer solutions to $\left(\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r \right)^2-1=k \cdot \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r^2$
Question: Compute the smallest positive integer $n \geq 2$ such that there exists an $n$-tuple of positive integers $(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ satisfying $$\left(\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r \right)^2-1=k \cdot \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r^2$$ for some positive integer $k$.
So far, I haven't done much. My first thought was to use the fact that $$\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2=\left(\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r \right)^2-2\sum_{1 \leq i, j \leq n, i \neq j} a_i a_j$$ However, the "double sum" quickly proved more difficult to work with, and so I abandoned this idea. In addition to this, I also rewrote the statement in the language of mods, but couldn't think of anything after I
rewrote the question statement.
————————————————————————
I then moved my attention to testing smaller cases. However, I really only knew how to work with the $n=2$ case.
For the $n=2$ case, $$(a_1+a_2)^2-1=k(a_1 ^2+a_2 ^2)$$ $$2a_1 a_2-1=(k-1)(a_1 ^2+a_2 ^2)$$ Using power-mean inequality, $$\sqrt{\frac{a_1 ^2+a_2^2}{2}} \geq \sqrt{a_1 ^2 a_2^2} \implies a_1^2+a_2^2 \geq 2a_1 a_2$$ and hence we have that $$2a_1 a_2-1 \geq (2k-2) a_1 a_2$$ $$-1 \geq (2k-4) a_1 a_2$$ which is a contradiction since $a_1, a_2>0$.
So, it is impossible for $k$ to be at least $2$.
If $k=1$, then $$(a_1+a_2)^2-1=a_1 ^2+a_2 ^2 \implies 2a_1 a_2-1=0$$ which is clearly impossible.
————————————————————————
I also tried testing the cases for $n=3$, $n=4$, and $n=5$ in Python (where $1 \leq a_i \leq 15$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$). However, these also yielded no solutions.
Any help would be appreciated!

In your $n=2$ case, you seem to have a mistake with "hence we have that", because you only replaced $a_1^2 + a_2^2$ with $\geq a_1 a_2$, instead of $ \geq 2a_1a_2$?

Hint: Show that $\sum a$ is odd, and hence $ 8 \mid k$. $\quad$ Then, show that $ n \geq 9$, and find a solution when $n = 9$.

@CalvinLin To your first comment, will edit. To your second comment, trying it now :)

This first write-up shows the problem-solving thought approach, so it's more detailed/conversational than needed. If you want a cleaned up solution, jump to the Quick Writeup in the next section.

First, we abstract away the specific values of $a_i$.

Let's set $ A = \sum a_i$ and $B = \sum a_i^2$, and the question becomes: $ A^2 -1 = kB$.
So we know that $ k \mid A^2 -1 = (A-1)(A+1)$. Apart from that, we don't have any further restrictions as yet.


Now, let's see what possible $(A, B)$ values we could have, given their definitions. One helpful observation is that $ A \equiv B \pmod{2}$.

If $A, B$ are even, then $A^2 - 1$ is odd but $kB$ is even, which is a contradiction.
Hence $A, B$ are odd. Furthermore, $k$ must contain all the even factors of $A^2 - 1$.

In particular, since $ 8 \mid A^2 - 1$, hence $ 8 \mid k$ so $ k \geq 8$.
Furthermore, if $A = 8p \pm 1$, then $16 \mid A^2 - 1$ so $ 16 \mid k$.




Now that we've found a restriction on $k$, does that give us a bound on $n$?

Another helpful observation is that $ A^2 \leq nB$ from power mean inequalities.
This tells us that $ kB = A^2 - 1 < A^2 \leq nB$ so $k < n$.


Combining these two observations, we get that $k$ is a multiple of 8 so at least 8, and $n$ is at least 9.

Great, that tells us that $n = 2, 3, 4$, will not work, even if we allowed for $a_i > 15$.


We have a lower bound on $n$, can it be achieved?

Can we find a solution set with $n = 9, k = 8$?
We have that $ A$ is odd, and $ A = \sum a_i^2 \geq n = 9$.
Does $A = 9$ work? Well, recall that with $A = 9 = 8 \times 1 + 1$, then $16 \mid A^2 - 1$ so $ 16 \mid k$ which contradicts $k = 8$. (Yes, this is a very fancy way to reject the $A = 9$ case, which has an obvious approach.)
The next higher value to test is $A = 11$, given $B = \frac { A^2 - 1 } { k} = 15$. Here, $ \{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2\} $ works.




Quick writeup:

Let $ A = \sum a_i, B = \sum a_i^2$.
Since $ A \equiv B \pmod{2}$, hence if $ A \equiv B \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$, then $ 1 \equiv A^2 - 1 \equiv kB \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$ which is a contradiction. Thus $A, B \equiv 1 \pmod{2}$.
Since $ 8 \mid A^2 -1$ and $B$ is odd, hence $ 8 \mid k$. In particular, $k$ is at least 8.
Since $ A^2 \leq nB$, so $ kB = A^2 -1 < A^2 \leq nB$ implies $k < n$.   In particular, $n$ is at least 9.
Finally, observe that $ \{ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2 \}$ is a solution set, so $n=9$ is indeed the smallest positive integer for which there is some $k$.


Recall that
$$\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 = \left(\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r \right)^2 - 2 \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n, \text{ } i \neq j} a_i a_j.$$
Since $a_m$ is an integer for $1 \leq m \leq n$, $\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n, \text{ } i \neq j} a_i a_j$ is an integer, and hence $2\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq n, \text{ } i \neq j} a_i a_j$ is always even. Therefore, $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2$ and $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r$ both have the same parity.
If $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r$ is even, then the left-hand side is odd while the right-hand side is even. Therefore, $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r$ must be odd.
Let $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r = 2s+1$ and $\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 = 2q+1$ for integers $s$ and $q$.
$$(2s+1)^2 - 1 = k(2q+1)$$
$$4s^2 + 4s = k(2q+1)$$
$$4s(s+1) = k(2q+1)$$
It is trivial to show that $s(s+1)$ is always even, and hence $8|k$.
By the power-mean inequality (particularly the quadratic-arithmetic part), we have that
$$\sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2} \geq \frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r$$
$$\frac{1}{n} \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 \geq \frac{1}{n^2} \left(\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r \right)^2$$
$$n \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 \geq \left(\sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r \right)^2$$
$$n \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 \geq k \cdot \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 + 1$$
$$(n-k) \sum^{n}_{r=1} a_r ^2 \geq 1$$
Since $k$ is a positive integer that is a multiple of $8$, the minimum possible value of $k$ is $8$. Therefore, $n \geq 9$.
$n=9$ is attainable by setting $k=8$ and
$$(a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, a_8, a_9) = (1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2).$$
Therefore, the answer is $\boxed{9}$.

As Calvin's hint suggests, first note $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r$ has the same parity as $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r^2$. This can easily be shown since the parity of $a_i$ and $a_i^2$ is the same, so both $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r$ and $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r^2$ are even iff there are an even number of odd $a_i$, and similarly both summations are odd iff there are an odd number of odd $a_i$. Note we also get this by rearranging your "first thought" equation to
$$\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r^2-\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r\right)^2=2\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n,\,i\neq j}a_ia_j$$
With the problem equation of
$$\left(\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r\right)^2-1=k\cdot\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r^2$$
if $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r$ is even, then the LHS is odd, but the RHS is even. Thus, we must instead have $\sum_{r=1}^{n}a_r$ being odd. Since the squares of all odd integers are congruent to $1$ modulo $8$, this means the LHS of the problem equation is divisible by $8$, so $8 \mid k$ as well.
As shown in Wikipedia's QM-AM-GM-HM inequalities, we have
$$\frac{\sum_{r=1}^n a_i}{n} \le \sqrt{\frac{\sum_{r=1}^n a_i^2}{n}} \;\;\to\;\; \left(\sum_{r=1}^n a_i\right)^2 \le n\left(\sum_{r=1}^n a_i^2\right)$$
Thus, if $k \ge n$, the problem equation gives that $\left(\sum_{r=1}^n a_i\right)^2 \gt n\left(\sum_{r=1}^n a_i^2\right)$, contradicting the above inequality. Thus, $k \lt n$ so, since $k \ge 8$, we get $n \ge 9$. Since the inequality above is an equality if and only if all $x_i$ are the same, for $k = 8$ and $n = 9$ to have a solution, we can investigate cases where the $a_i$ values are mostly all the same. As all being the same isn't permitted, let's instead first check having $8$ be the same value of $j$ and $1$ be a different value of $m$. We then get
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(8j + m)^2 - 1 & = 8(8j^2 + m^2) \\
64j^2 + 16jm + m^2 - 1 & = 64j^2 + 8m^2 \\
-1 & = 7m^2 - 16jm
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Since $m$ divides the RHS, then $m \mid -1$, so $m = 1$. However, the RHS becomes $7 - 16j \le -9$, so this isn't possible.
We next check on $7$ of the $a_i$ values being $j$ and $2$ being a different $m$. The problem equation then becomes
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(7j + 2m)^2 - 1 & = 8(7j^2 + 2m^2) \\
49j^2 + 28jm + 4m^2 - 1 & = 56j^2 + 16m^2 \\
-7j^2 + 28jm - 12m^2 - 1 & = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Treating the above equation as a quadratic in $j$, the discriminant must be a perfect square, i.e., there's a positive integer $d$ where
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
d^2 & = (28m)^2 - 4(-7)(-12m^2 - 1) \\
& = 28^2m^2 + 28(-12m^2 - 1) \\
& = 28(28m^2 - 12m^2 - 1) \\
& = 4(7)(16m^2 - 1)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
Checking values, we see $m = 1$ doesn't work, but $m = 2$ gives that $d^2 = 4(7)(63) \;\to\; d = 14(3)$. Thus, the quadratic formula gives that
$$j = \frac{-28(2)\pm 14(3)}{-14} = 4\pm 3 = 1, 7$$
This actually provides $2$ solutions, i.e., where $2$ of the $a_i$ are $2$, while $7$ of the $a_i$ are $1$ for one solution, and $7$ for the second one. This shows $n = 9$ (with $k = 8$) is the smallest value of $n$ which works.

FYI The claim that "the $a_i$ values should likely mostly be all the same" isn't true (though it could be a useful wishful thinking to start). That's because we're to that close to the equality case, but instead have $ A^2 - 1 = (n-1)B < nB - 1$.   For example, ${ 1, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10 }$ is also a solution set.

@CalvinLin Thank you for your feedback. You're correct the $a_i$ values don't necessarily need to mostly all be the same. As such, I've changed my wording to instead indicate that it's something to investigate.
